# Message storage and retrieval

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to update an old system in my discord bot that sends a random "quote" said by the server owner, currently its just an array full of the quotes but I have to add them by hand and it's never been a problem but I want the other server members to be able to add their own. I know there is a way to store and retrieve messages but I keep getting lost, any advice?

I want it to be something like !addquote "the quote goes here" and the bot stores it then when using !quote it sends a random one from the list!
It may be important to note that my bot is currently hosted on heroku and not my computer!

Comment: You can use a json file that gets added to every time you say something

Answer (score 0):

If your list of quotes is being stored in an array, you could always [`Array.prototype.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) the quote and add it to the array.

```js
array.push('quote')
```

However, the array will reset if you restart your bot unless you store the quotes in a database

Comment: the problem is that when the op restarts the bot they get lost

Comment: I know, that's why I'm suggesting the usage of a database

Comment: sorry, didn't read the last part. the problem is that this answer doesn't solve the problem

Comment: The problem was that OP didn't know how to store user-added quotes in the array automatically, if I understand correctly. That's what I answered.

Comment: Hmmm. For some reason when i read the post i thought that the op said they were already using array.push. sorry!